# MATCH function won't work with a cell reference value when both range and value are same type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use `=MAX(C6:H900)` to find the max value in a range. I put that value in K29.

Then I try to use `=MATCH(K29,C6:H900)` to find that value in the range to return the row.  MATCH returns `#N/A`.

I checked the type of both K29 and the range and they are both v. If I use `=MATCH(K29,K29)`, a `1` is returned.

So MATCH does seem to find the value but as soon as I expand the range, MATCH returns #N/A.    I am using Excel Version 16.40. I could really use some help.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of excel sheet]

Comment: Your formula fails because MATCH expects a single column (or row).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AGGREGATE`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,(K1=$C$1:$H$20)*ROW($C$1:$H$20),1)
```

[image]